# JNDI Lookup exception

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi

I have created a dynamic web project in WAS 7.0.0.25. I have configured datasource as jdbc/DWLConfig in the WAS. I am trying to lookup this datasource in the servlet from the web project i have created.

if i give java:comp/env/jdbc/DWLConfig, it is giving me NameNotFoundException. But if i give jdbc/DWLConfig, then it is working fine.

Actually, from the servlet, i am calling another project which i dont have access to edit, always looks like java:comp/env/jdbc/DWLConfig. So it is throwing exception for me.

Do i need to add any reference in the web project which i have created.?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: NameNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the base JNDI. You will notice why it is not working from the following example:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

// Right
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DWLConfig");

// Wrong. because base JNDI already created.
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DWLConfig");
```

Comment: Sorry i couldnt get it. Where does base JNDI created. You are just looking up in the 2nd line

Comment: They might be created inside your library project